# Return child of object array in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to return the matching object from an array of objects in mongoose/mongodb but I can't seem to get it right.

My schema currently looks like this:

```
items: {
    left: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    total: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    each: [{
        name: String
    }]
}
```

This makes each object within `each` to get its own object id. Now I am trying to query this with mongoose, I've tried both `$in` and `$elemMatch` and a plain `.find({ items.each._id: req.params.id })`.

More specific

```
Project.findOne({ 'items.each': { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.id } } }).exec()
```

I want to return an object like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(23426456234),
    name: "My name is"
}
```

But why can't I get this?

Comment: Have you checked if `req.params.id` is an objectid or a string? And are you sure that the `each` objects are being saved correctly in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
db.getCollection('projects').findOne({"items.each._id" : 
ObjectId("57ffc4396270adff8b273f72")},{"items.each.$":1})
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ffc4396270adff8b273f71"),
    "items" : {
        "each" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "sdfsd",
                "_id" : ObjectId("57ffc4396270adff8b273f72")
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

OR:

```
db.getCollection('projects').aggregate(
{$unwind: "$items.each"},
{$match:{"items.each._id" : ObjectId("57ffc4396270adff8b273f72")}},
{$project:{_id: 0, each: "$items.each"}}
)
```

Output:

```
{
    "each" : {
        "name" : "sdfsd",
        "_id" : ObjectId("57ffc4396270adff8b273f72")
    }
}
```